# Inner Join Common Column values are Overwritten

Tags: hibernate, spring

There are more than two common fields  `(id ,created_by,modified_date)`in DB in different tables.

While using inner join that same column name field values   are overwrite .This is working fine in query browser tools but not works in spring 3, hibernate 3 environment.

Query:

```
select i.modified_date ,l.modified_date 
from illness i inner join illness_history l on i.id=l.ill_hist_illness_id
```

Spring Configuration:

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>

<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.project.**.*</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics"> true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be due to  an unresolved bug in hibernate . Check [here](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-3988) . Your solution would be inclde an Alias and test .

```
select i.modified_date m1 ,l.modified_date m2, from illness i inner join illness_history l on i.id=l.ill_hist_illness_id
```

Comment: hi Aravind, I tried this but it is working in Query browser only.. if i try to execute this query in Spring 3,hibernate 3 environment it shows the following error Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
 at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92) Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'modified_date' not found.
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073) i dont have any idea to solve this problem....